# Sequelize - Implementing a trash for my models

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, recycle-bin

I'm building the backend of my e-shop using Sequelize. I have defined models for `clients`, `products`, `orders`, etc. I want any instance of these models to be "trashable", *i.e.* just like deleted instances, I want trashed instances not to appear in the results of calls to `<Model>.findAll()`, `<ModelA>.get<ModelB>s()` or even `<ModelA>.findAll({ include: [{ model: <ModelB> }]`. But I still want to be able to query those trashed instances (and restore them eventually).

The solution I'm considering is adding a `.status` property to my models (`ENUM('active', 'trashed')`), and then adding a `beforeFind` hook to all my models to filter out instances that are not `active` unless the query is explicitly searching for id(s) or `trashed` items. 
I worry about the potential complexity of the queries passed to my `beforeFind` hook, though. How to detect what the queries are searching for and how should they be modified to filter-out trashed items? And there are probably other shortcomings to this solution I didn't even consider…

Before giving implementation a try, I wanted to know if others had given this *pattern* a try, how they did it and what difficulties they faced. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for the `paranoid` option?

Comment: Exactly! Clearly Sequelize docs lack a paragraph on the use-cases and implications of `paranoid`.